# Aliasing in .NET

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

Is it possible to create an alias to existing types and use that alias through out the project?

For example, create

```
CustomerID = System.UInt32
```

and use CustomerID as a datatype?

Version : .NET Framework 4.0

(With the "using" keyword we would be able to create an alias, but it is not useful as it does not work across files.)

Any other ideas?

Comment: The reason why you have the use the `using` keyword on a namespace is because it is a very bad idea to create a global `using`. Imagine someone else using a `CustomerID` type in a different context and gets an unsigned integer back instead of their expected type. By restricting it to only a namespace, you prevent against this type of collision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the correct answer to this question is:

No, that's (unfortunately?) not possible. :(

---

Edit 1: *However*, you *can* (kind of) simulate this by making your own `struct`, and providing implicit conversions to/from the type you want. It's not exactly magical but it might work, depending on the situation.

---

Edit 2: I haven't ever used this feature before, but [type forwarding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.typeforwardedtoattribute.aspx) *might* be helpful. It only forwards to another entire assembly, though, so it probably won't work for simple cases.

Comment: Thought of structure/record as a workaround, are there any smarter ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem possible. However, for which reason do you want to do this?

If your reason is **readability**, consider the following:

You can already use your identifiers to indicate it is e.g. a `customerID`. What you are essentially doing when trying to rename `UInt32` to `CustomerID` is making it look like a new type. Only when a type needs additional behavior or values it is useful to consider it a 'new' type. If you ever developed in C++, you can appreciate the **convention** caused by not allowing this in C#. You know what to expect from a `UInt32`.

If your reason is **preparing yourself for changes**:

E.g. suppose after some time you decide you also want to support negative ID's. This should be solved by encapsulating this possible expected behavior in a new type. So no renaming is necessary.

Comment: Another reason is added type safety. Imagine you have a method `GetItem(uint customerID, uint itemID)`. Someone could accidentally put the arguments around the wrong way. However, if you use new types, such as `GetItem(CustomerID customerID, ItemID itemID)`, then mixing up the arguments will be a compile-time error.